Seeking help, electron cannot access cookies when requesting cross-domain api
Is there a solution?
When using axios or fetch to request a cross-domain interface, the response object does not contain set-cookie, but it exists in the response header in the browser network.
My request address http://bgm.tv/login
I request to bring credentials when needed.
axios  withCredentials: true
or
fetch credentials: 'include'

Try to close webPreferences webSecurity No effect
Set cookie security

session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived(
  { urls: filter },
  (details, callback) => {
    if (details.responseHeaders) {
      if (details.responseHeaders["set-cookie"]) {
        const newCookies = details.responseHeaders["set-cookie"].map(
          (item) => `${item.split("; ")[0]}; Secure; SameSite=None`,
        );
        details.responseHeaders["set-cookie"] = newCookies;
      }
    }

    callback({
      cancel: false,
      responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders,
    });
  },
);


Secure only valid in https
After building, still unable to get set cookie.
Can anyone provide a solution?
